# Bootstrap tour - Getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'onNext' of undefined

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-tour

I am trying to implement bootstrap-tour in my website. However, when I click on next on the tour popover I always get below error and the tour doesn't move to next step.

```
bootstrap-tour.js:469 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onNext' of undefined
at Tour._showNextStep (bootstrap-tour.js:469)
at Tour._callOnPromiseDone (bootstrap-tour.js:812)
at Tour.next (bootstrap-tour.js:178)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap-tour.js:741)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery-1.9.1.js:3074)
at HTMLDocument.elemData.handle (jquery-1.9.1.js:2750)
Tour._showNextStep @ bootstrap-tour.js:469
Tour._callOnPromiseDone @ bootstrap-tour.js:812
Tour.next @ bootstrap-tour.js:178
(anonymous) @ bootstrap-tour.js:741
dispatch @ jquery-1.9.1.js:3074
elemData.handle @ jquery-1.9.1.js:2750
```

Below is what I have added as tour steps:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var tour = new Tour({

    steps: [
        {
          element: ".stepClass",
          title: "Title1",            
          content: "Message 1.",
          debug:true//Set this option to true to have some useful informations printed in the console.
        },
        {
          element: ".stepClass2",
          title: "Title2",
          content: "Message 2",
         debug:true
        }

      ],
      backdrop: true,
      storage: false

  });
 tour.init();
 tour.start();

});
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: can u explain what issue you are facing exactly.

Comment: Hi the bootstrap tour is not working. First element in the tour gets highlighted. However, when I click next, it throws above mentioned error.

Comment: Never mind...looks like had some issue earlier with finding the element. I have tried again now,  and it's working. Thanks!

Comment: Your most welcome